# Validate user input in AppSync DynamoDB Resolvers

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, serverless, aws-appsync

I have AWS AppSync API with DynamoDb and I can create and get data from it with [DynamoDb Resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html). (VTL templates)

I am not sure how can I do the user input validation with VTL templates. I want to make sure the contact's "firstName" is between 2 - 30 characters in length.

How can I achieve this with VTL? Is there a way to do this kind of validation within the GraphQL schema itself?

Here's my GraphQL Schema,

```
schema {
   query: Query
   mutation: Mutation
}

type Mutation {
   createContact(contact: ContactInput!): Contact! 
}

type Contact {
    contactId: ID!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
}

input ContactInput {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a nice way of doing this in GraphQL, but you can do it easily in VTL using either `$util.validate` or `$util.error` (see [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html)). They both have the same result of adding an item to the `errors` array.

Here's a demo of `$util.validate`:
https://mappingtool.dev/app/appsync/bee55bd607e2166091451e7a7959318e

Here's a demo of `$util.error`:
https://mappingtool.dev/app/appsync/006d6c05e8bb7257c6cebce34494994c

Comment: Thank you for the help Zac.